# DateTimeOffset parsing different in NET Console App vs NET Isolated Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

```cs
var timestamp = "Fri Sep 8 07:00:37 BST 2023";

var isBst = timestamp.Contains("BST");
var tz = isBst ? "BST" : "GMT";
var formatString = $"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss {tz} yyyy";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(timestamp, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In an external web api, a London timestamp is returned verbosely. I need to parse it into a DateTimeOffset. In my NET console application, this  runs and prints `08.09.2023 07:00:37 +02:00` to the console. The same code throws an error in my isolated Azure Functions app, which technically is also just a (hosted) console application. Note: timestamp is hardcoded here for illustration purposes.

I am at a loss on why this is, do you have any idea? My end goal is to just have a DateTimeOffset representation of that text-literal timestamp. How would you go about parsing it?

The error message is:

```
Result: Failure Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
(String 'Fri Sep 8 07:00:37 BST 2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)
---> System.FormatException: String 'Fri Sep 8 07:00:37 BST 2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, ReadOnlySpan`1 format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style, TimeSpan& offset) 
at System.DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(String input, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider, DateTimeStyles styles)
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

My Azure Function App is configured to use my local timezone

```json
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE",
    "value": "W. Europe Standard Time",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
```

Comment: That's not a timestamp, that's a completely custom and *ambiguous* format - what does `BST` mean? There's no standard or formal list of 3-letter acronyms and the same one *can* be used by different countries.

Comment: The "fix" is improper for handling GMT vs BST is improper. You're attempting to get `ParseExact` to ignore it, but it contains valuable information for two hours every year. There are two different hours in the fall for which everything but the TZ can be different. I don't know if the error you are getting is related to that or not, but solving the problem you ask about is moot since it would leave that problem in place.

Comment: BST is British Summer Time. Now that you say it, the problem did not occur when the summer time was not observed and London is on GMT (which is well-known apparently by NET).

Comment: No it's not, and in fact your own working code ignored it. You got back `07:00:37 +02:00`, as if the string was a *Central European* date string

Comment: @ikegami the question's code uses BST and the actual output is Central European (+2:00 in the summer). In the *working* code, BST was ignored silently. In the failing code, it was rejected

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I posted that before your edit. Comment deleted.

Comment: @ikegami I only noticed that later too - when I run that code I got +03:00 (Greek summer time): `08/09/2023 07:00:37 +03:00`

Comment: Is there something like `+00:00` and `+01:00` that `ParseExact` understands? If so, you could replace `GMT` and `BST` with that and use the appropriate pattern in the format.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I have updated the question to include my main goal, which is to jsut parse it into a DateTimeOffset object. I also realise that the printed TZ is incorrect. Still there remains the question on why this is working (i.e. not throwing) locally vs in Azure Function.

Comment: Re "*Still there remains the question on why this is working*", No. Again, it did not work "in Azure Function", since it gave `08.09.2023 07:00:37 +02:00` instead of `08.09.2023 07:00:37 +01:00`. And again, it's probably related. If it's not related, then your approach is fundamentally flawed, so there would be no point in addressing the question when it will give incorrect results.

Comment: Replace `GMT` with `+00:00` and `BST` with `+01:00` in the input string, and use `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` as the pattern. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that worked! Replacing the above values with their numeric equivalents nad using the format specifier `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` the timestamp parses correctly into `08.09.2023 06:00:37 +00:00`

Comment: Instead of hard coding the offsets, you can get the offsets from a `TimeZoneInfo` object by calling [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Is the string that contains "BST" coming from an API on an external web app? Or are you scrapping a UI page? If the former, it's a bug because it is not a valid standard format for data interchange.

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds: It is coming from an external API response.

Comment: Thanks for all your comment this far! I have learned that my above approach was flawed and also that the console app, just ignored the 'BST' and set the timezone to my current locale... As stated above, by replacing BST to +01:00 I was succesfully able to parse the timstamp into a correct one in the console app. However, Azure Functions still complains with the error `Result: Failure Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (String 'Fri Sep 8 15:17:42 +01:00 2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` I've used  `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` as the format specifier

Comment: Try this as string ```var timestamp = "Fri Sep 8 07:00:37 +01:00 2023";``` and this as format specifier ```var formatString = $"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss +01:00 yyyy";```, im quite sure, now this will work.

Comment: @baouss did the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

I do agree with @Panagiotis Kanavos the give code uses BST and the real answer is Central European. when you are using Isolated Function app code, BST was rejected and got same error as below:

[image]

But as per @ikegami, when I changed BST to +01:00 and GMT to +00:00 it did worked for me too:

[image]

[image]